# Update Column value by replacing a specific string

Tags: sql

I have a column which holds data in a row like this:

```
Col1 '2118,2110,2114,2112',
Col2 '2110,2111,2112,2113,2114,2115,2117,2118,2119,2152,2153' and 
Col3 '2110,2111,2113,2114'.
```

Now I want to replace `2110` from every column when I run a delete command to delete `2110`.

What I tried is (I am doing this for col1 value - I am adding a comma at start and end of string so it meets the result i.e. if the comma is after 2110 as '2110,' at start as ',2110' and from start and end as ',2110,')

```
DECLARE @TagId VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TagId = '2118,2110,2114,2112'
print 'Select Tag ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = ',' + @TagId + ','
print 'Adding comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = REPLACE(@TagId,',2110,',',')
print 'Replace the string ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = SUBSTRING(@TagId,1,LEN(@TagId))
print 'Replace start comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = SUBSTRING(@TagId,0,LEN(@TagId) -1)
print 'Replace end comma' + @TagId
SELECT @TagId
```

Now the problem is its not replacing the comma from start and end which I added at start. Please suggest me what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
DECLARE @TagId VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TagId = '2118,2110,2114,2112'
print 'Select Tag ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = ',' + @TagId + ','
print 'Adding comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = REPLACE(@TagId,',2110,',',')
print 'Replace the string ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = SUBSTRING(@TagId,2,LEN(@TagId))
print 'Replace start comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = SUBSTRING(@TagId,0,LEN(@TagId))
print 'Replace end cooma' + @TagId
SELECT @TagId
```

More on [SUBSTRING](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx)

Comment: you added 2 instead of 1 in the substring part for replacing first comma and also remove (-1) for last comma. Are you sure its giving correct result always. Here I am not specific to the first col value only.. it should run for all values where '2110' will found

Comment: I had also tried this before adding this post (he code you suggested by adding 2 and removing (-1)) but the point is start comma is at start at position 1, not at second and same for last comma. So I think its not a universal solutions to apply. I am working on live application so there is no margin for error.

Answer (score 0):

why are you adding the comma at the start and end?
Surely you could just a do replace like so:

```
DECLARE @TagId VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TagId = '2118,2110,2114,2112'
SET @TagId = REPLACE(@TagId, '2110' , '')
```

Then remove the double comma:

```
SET @TagId = REPLACE(@TagId, ',' , ',')
```

Comment: I am adding comma at start and end because we can have '2110' at start as '2110' only, '2110,another id' and in between like '122,2110,1245' and at the end '556,1212,2110'. So what I am doing is I am adding the comma in advance so it will cover all the scenarios..

Comment: your query will result: 2118,,2114,2112

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
DECLARE @TagId VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @TagId = '2118,2110,2114,2112'
print 'Select Tag ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = ',' + @TagId + ','
print 'Adding comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = REPLACE(@TagId,',2110,',',')
print 'Replace the string ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = CASE WHEN LEN(@TagId) > 1 THEN SUBSTRING(@TagId,2,LEN(@TagId)) 
             ELSE @TagId END
print 'Replace start comma ' + @TagId
SET @TagId = SUBSTRING(@TagId,1,LEN(@TagId) -1)
print 'Replace end comma ' + @TagId
SELECT @TagId
```

Comment: What if I have a value like  '2118,2110,2114,2112,12110' then it will replace '2110' from last value and result '2118,2110,2114,2112,1' which is wrong result?

Comment: Yes, it works, but the length of @TagId is greater than 1 then what is the use of case you added... My point is why its not working with SUBSTRING(@TagId,1,LEN(@TagId)) as the comma is at start

Comment: And also can you suggest how to combine this into single query to update the field value in db i.e. update table1 set TagId = the single query from above where CAST(TagId AS VARCHAR) like '%2110%'